# Virtex-6 Ethernet Implementation

Tags: fpga, ethernet, xilinx

I am trying to implement the example design provided after creating the "Virtex-6 Embedded Tri-Mode Ethernet MAC Wrapper". I included all the design files as shown below.

[image]
I have some changes in the constrain file by finding the pins from ML605 user guide as below.
[image]

imageI implemented the design on the Board. I am sending the data from scapy from cmd and observing in wireshark using the below commands.

```
x=Ether(src = "34:66:F9:24:F8:09",dst = "00:0A:35:02:DC:C5")/IP(src="192.168.56.1", dst="192.168.56.2")/UDP(dport=54321,sport=15293)/Raw(load="Hello world.. Sending data to check the transmission. Please acknowledge this message. Thank you.")
 
sendp(x,count=1)
```

Only the transmitted packets are shown in the wireshark. There is no data coming from the FPGA. Should I make any changes in the constrain file to match my Board? Also the LEDs present near Ethernet PHY connection are not blinking, is there any problem with this? I have attached the complete constrain file used.

[Constrain file link](https://github.com/avdssrk/Ethernet_mac/blob/b0d0c775ccb08db15b89431ca764ab0987747ee1/eth_1g_example_design.ucf)

I think there is a problem with clocks on the FPGA, can anyone say how to make proper connection. Also if I want to observe the signals on Chipscope, what should be the clock trigger signal to use?